# PL/pgSQL Return SETOF Records Error

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am relatively new to postgresql and battling my way to get familiarized with it. I had run in to an error while writing a new pl/sql function. **ERROR:  type "ordered_parts" does not exist**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_ordered_parts(var_bill_to integer)
  RETURNS SETOF ordered_parts AS
$BODY$
declare

    var_ordered_id record;
    var_part ordered_parts;

begin

    for var_ordered in select order_id from view_orders where bill_to = var_bill_to
    loop

        for var_part select os.po_num,os.received,os.customer_note,orders.part_num,orders.description,orders.order_id,orders.remaining_quantity from (select vli.part_num,vli.description,vli.order_id,vli.quantity - vli.quantity_shipped as remaining_quantity from view_line_items as vli where vli.order_id in (select order_id from view_orders where bill_to = var_bill_to and order_id = var_ordered.order_id) and vli.quantity - vli.quantity_shipped > 0)as orders left join order_sales as os on orders.order_id = os.order_id
        then

            -- Then we've found a leaf part
            return next var_part;

        end if;

    end loop;

end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION get_ordered_parts(integer) OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: Not being familiar with PLSQL, I would assume the declared variables are your problem, should you also declare the datatype? http://www.plsql-tutorial.com/plsql-variables.htm

Comment: What makes you think `ordered_parts` is a valid type? is it the name of a relation?

Comment: No its not a relation name. I am just trying to return a set of records.

Comment: Then what did you expect Postgres to interpret from `RETURNS SETOF ordered_parts`? If you just want an anonymous record type then the type is `record` as you've done for one of the vars in your `declare` block. So the function declaration should say `RETURNS SETOF record`. As it is, you're telling Postgres it returns instances of a type called `ordered_parts`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks a lot, its working now after changing **ordered_parts** to record

Comment: @IMSoP Post that as an answer so it can be accepted.

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto I wasn't sure if there was more to it. Since it appears not, I've tidied up my explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you have declared the return type of your function to be `SETOF ordered_parts`, but it doesn't know what kind of thing `ordered_parts` is. Within your `Declare` block you also have a variable declared as this same type (`var_part ordered_parts`).

If you had a table or view called `ordered_parts`, then its "row type" would be automatically created as a type, but this is not the case here. if you just want to use an arbitrary row from a result set, you can just use the generic type `record`.

So in this case your function should say `RETURNS SETOF record`, and your `Declare` block `var_part record`.

**Bonus tip:** rather than looping over the result of your query and running `RETURN NEXT` on each row, you can use `RETURN QUERY` to throw the whole result set into the returned set in one go. See [this Postgres manual page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING).

Comment: Firstly thanks a lot for helping me out.I tried to modify the code according to your suggestions. I ran in to another issue and i keep getting **ERROR:  set-valued function called in context that cannot accept a set** **CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function "get_ordered_parts" line 9 at RETURN QUERY**

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_ordered_parts(var_bill_to integer)
  RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$
declare

 var_ordered_id record;

begin
    
    for var_ordered_id in select order_id from view_orders where bill_to = var_bill_to
    loop
   return query select * ....
       
    end loop;

    return;

end;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION get_ordered_parts(integer) OWNER TO postgres;

Comment: How are you calling the function? When calling a function which returns a set, you have to use `SELECT * FROM function_name()`, not `SELECT function_name()`. Additionally, because the return type is an anonymous record, you have to specify a name and type for the columns when calling it, so e.g. `SELECT * FROM function_name() as foo (a int, b text)`. There's an example [in the docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html) - search for "CREATE FUNCTION distributors".

Comment: Thanks a lot,U made my day. I was using SELECT function_name() instead of SELECT * from function_name()

Answer (score 2):

just note - your code is perfect example how don't write stored procedure ever. For some longer results it can be extremely slow. Minimally two cycles can be joined to one, or better, you can use just only one RETURN QUERY statement. Next issue is zero formatting of embedded SQL - good length of line is between 70 and 100 chars - writing long SQL statement to one line going to zero readability and maintainability code.

Relation database is not array, and any query has some cost, so don't use nested FOR if you really don't need it. I am sorry for offtopic.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the valuable suggestion and by using return query i got rid of for loop. Regarding the length of the query i will make a note of it and will make it much more legible.